# Action bar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled not working on ICS

Tags: android

In an activity I have:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and for that activity in the AndroidManifest

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

and this provides the up button that works correctly on Jelly Bean (4.3), but on ICS (4.0.3) both on a physical device and on the emulator, nothing happens when this button is clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, android:parentActivityName attribute supported only after API level 16 (JellyBean) One alternative is using [support-library:v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) combined with [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html).

There is a great training material about this topic (include compatibility issue).
please check 
- http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html