# Navigate back from settings activity

Tags: android

I'm playing around with Android Studio so I created a SettingsActivity using the wizard and I'm faced with the problem that it is not possible to navigate from this settings activity back to the main activity using the "up" arrow in the Actionbar.

The setup of the Actionbar looks like this:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Actionbar is not null btw.
And the parentActitvityName is set in the AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.demo.app.MainActivity" />
 </activity>
```

However, a click on the arrow does nothing. Not even onOptionsItemSelected gets triggered.

Seems like this is exactly the same problem
[Action bar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled not working on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716499/action-bar-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-not-working-on-ics) but navigating back from a detail to an overview activity is working fine in the very same app. Moreover I set MinSDK to 15 and TargetSDK to 23.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method on your AppCompatPrefernceActivity and make it like this

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: The method does not get called on the main-settings-activity.

Comment: you can override the method. By the way I will edit my answer, copy and paste it on your activity

Comment: yep, this is what i already have but when i click on "up" this method isn't called.

Comment: hmmm strange, try to delete this line actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Comment: did you override the onCreateOptionsMenu method?

Comment: Does not help, unfortunately. No, I didn't. Logcat does not print anything when I click on the up button btw.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had to put this code inside AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java and remove the method from SettingsActivity.java, then it worked

Answer (score 2):

Vspallas answer is correct. The mistake was on my side. I had an onOptionsItemSelected method inside the preferenceFragment, not in the Activity. Mea culpa.

Comment: You could call getActivity().onBackPressed() from within the fragment, to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inside the settings activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then in androidManifest is the same as that you have did

```
<activity
   android:name=".SettingsActivity"
   android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_settings">
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
      android:value="com.example.app_name.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

this `com.example.app_name` is you App package name